# Erro de acesso à memória!

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou tentando implementar um `BINA` com `Delphi 7` usando `Super Bina`!

Adicionei o componente no `form` e num `botão`  fiz:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.btnAbreConClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  texto: String;
begin
  spBina.Conectado:=true;
  spBina.LeiaDTMF(texto,100);
  ShowMessage(texto);
end;
```

e no `onDTMF` fiz

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.spBinaDTMF(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  Buffer : String;
  Contador: Integer;
begin

  // Define o valor do Time Out
  Sleep(500);
  // Confere o número total de bytes dentro do pacote enviado
  Contador := spBina.InputCount;
  // Lê o pacote enviado e armazena no Buffer
  spBina.Read(Buffer, Contador);
  // Alimenta um campo Memo com os dados recebidos
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Buffer);
end;
```

Então,
   no **código** do `botão`, ao chegar o **ring** da **linha telefônica** eu recebo **RING** no `ShowMessage`. Só isso!
   no código do `onDTMF`, ao chegar `spBina.Read(Buffer, Contador);`, está dando erro de acesso à **memória**!

Como corrigir isso?

```
// Ler no modo sincrono
function TSspBina.ReadAsync(var Buffer; Count: Integer; var AsyncPtr: PAsync): Integer;
var
  Success: Boolean;
  BytesTrans: DWORD;
begin
  AsyncPtr^.Kind := okRead;
  Success := ReadFile(FHandle, Buffer, Count, BytesTrans, @AsyncPtr^.Overlapped)
    or (GetLastError = ERROR_IO_PENDING);

  if not Success then
    raise ECspBina.Create(CError_ReadFailed, GetLastError);

  Result := BytesTrans;
end;
```

quando faz o `ReadFile`